# determine client reconnect to server

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I use client disconnect event on the server to determine when the client disconnected from the server. But I need to know when the client has reconnected. Can I do this? I am running SignalR in a WebView on a mobile device and I assume loss of signal causes SignalR disconnect to fire on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try having your Hub implement the IConnected interface, more info [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs).

This gives you these methods:

```
Task Disconnect()
Task Connect()
Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
```